# Bootstrap tabs inside disabled fieldset not working with Firefox

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I've created a form containing a fieldset inside which are navigation tabs.

When this fieldset is disabled, the tabs are working normally when using Chrome/Chromium; but when using
Firefox, they are not: the browser is updating the location hash and the tab is not opened!

Any idea?

Best regards,

Thierry

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been tagged as a Firefox defect.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1637321 for more details...